# This is the highest any of my students has/have scored

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> This is the highest any of my students has/have ever scored.
> *(Stating that only 1 student of all my students has scored the
> highest marks)*

Should we use “has” or “have” here? I would personally use “have” as it sounds better. But here we are talking about only 1 student of all the students scoring the highest. So, would we use “has”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use “has,” because as you said, only *one* person scored the highest. It does sound a bit odd because it is immediately preceded by “students,” which is plural, and our natural instinct is to attach “have” to plural nouns. But you could rephrase the sentence this way to help you test out the correct word:

> This is the highest **anyone *has*** ever scored.
>
> This is the highest **anyone *have*** ever scored.

That should make it a little easier to see which noun applies.

Comment: I can’t say “this is the highest anyone has scored” since that would apply the statement to “everyone”. I am talking about a specific group of people which is “my students”. And I am implying that none of my students ever scored that high earlier, that one particular student broke the record and scored the highest.

Comment: @AydenFerguson i’m not suggesting a change to your example, I’m rephrasing another way to express a similar idea that uses a simpler term. In other words, “anyone” serves the same function in my example as “any of my students” serves in yours.

Comment: Oh okay, after the edit it makes it clearer what you meant. :-)